# preg_replace last slash and directory name or file name

Tags: php, regex

File:

```
C:\Some\Location\index
```

I just want to replace \index with \example

```
echo preg_replace('/[\\\|\/]{1}.*?$/', '\example', $file);
```

It just keeps being too greedy.  I don't know of any modifiers that would help that problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `.` with `[^/\]`, which matches anything but the slashes. I also changed the regex delimiter to `@`, since slashes aren't appropriate when handling paths.

```
$str='C:\\Some\\Location\\index';
echo preg_replace('@[/\\\\][^/\\\\]+$@', '\example', $str);
# echoes: C:\Some\Location\example
```

Answer (score 4):

how about `echo preg_replace('/[\\\|\/]{1}[^\\\/]*?$/', '\example', $file);` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for that if you can use forward slashes instead of those ugly backslashes (yes, windows **does** support forward slashes):

```
$str = 'C:/Some/Location/index';
echo dirname($str).'/example';
```

Comment: Well, I can't assume that any platform uses one or the other as far as slashes go, unless I'm replacing slashes, but that seems unnecessary. @simon, I think regular expressions are very appropriate here.

Comment: @Senica - to perform path manipulation?  I'm gonna stick to my original opinion.

Comment: You do not need backslashes on any platform. Forward slashes are the way to go. They work on Linux/Unix, OSX and Windows - and probably on most/all exotic systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace( '/(^.*?)\\([^\\]+)$/', '$1\\example', $file );
```

#### And a RegExp-less solution:

```
$path = explode( '\\', $file );
array_splice( $path, -1, 1, 'example' )
$file = implode( '\\', $path );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using regular expressions,

```
 echo preg_replace('/[^\/\\]*$/', 'example', $file)
```

will do.

I recommend using

```
 echo dirname($file).'\example'
```

instead, which will safely handle forward and backslashes, the root directory etc.